# React children iterating

Tags: reactjs

Which method is better/safer, recommended in general, for iterating/mapping react's children?

```
this.props.children.map(c => <span>new child</span>);
```

OR

```
React.Children.map(c => <span>new child</span>);
```

Answer (score 7):

`React.Children.map` is better because it handles `null` and `undefined` cases.

> If children is null or undefined, returns null or undefined rather than an array.

Comment: The docs should say "*... rather than throwing an error*", because that's what happens if you try doing `map()` on `undefined` or `null`. You don't get an (empty) array in those cases which seems to be suggested here.

Comment: @Chris I think they meant this function, not comparison to first approach. So this sentence in other words would be: "Function returns array by default but will return null or undefined if children is null or undefined".

Comment: There is some discrepancy here either way. "Rather than" suggests doing otherwise than what is normal or typical, and no map() returns an array in these cases.